# How to keep laravel collection sorted when transform to JSON for AJAX request

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, sorting

I encounter a problem with data ordering when i transform my collection array from laravel query to json object for AJAX request. How can i keep my data ordered as in the collection ?

Here is the part of my view for ajax :

```
    $('#sorting').on('change', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        var sort = $('#sort').val();
        $('#content').addClass('d-none');
        $('#loading').removeClass('d-none');
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('search') }}",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                sort: sort
            },
            success:function(response)
            {
                var data = JSON.parse(response.success);
                var html = '';
                $('#content').empty();
                console.log(data);
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    html += `
                        <p class="text-dark">`+data[i].date_début+`</p>
                    `;
                });
                $('#content').html(html);
                $('#loading').addClass('d-none');
            },
            error: function(response) {
                $('#content').empty();
                $('#content').append(response.error);
                $('#loading').addClass('d-none');
            }
        });
        $('#content').removeClass('d-none');
    });
```

Here is the port of my controller where i order collection before retreive it to my view via AJAX:

```
       if($request->sort){
            switch($request->sort){
                case "date-asc":
                    $events = $events->sortBy('date_début');
                    break;

                case "date-desc":
                    $events = $events->sortByDesc('date_début');
                    break;

                case "prix-asc":
                    $events = $events->sortBy('low');
                    break;

                case "prix-desc":
                    $events = $events->sortByDesc('low');
                    break;

                default:
                    return response()->json(['error'=>'Une erreur est survenue']);
                    break;
            }
            return response()->json(['success'=>json_encode($events)]);
        }
```

I hope you'll understand my problem/question.

Many thanks !